# ODBC SQL, Using a reserved word in a where clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I have a problem where I need to search for a value in a ODBC which is a reserved word.
So:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE AccountNumber = 'Sum'
```

In this case, 'Sum' is a reserved word and so I get a syntax error.
In access the error is "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect"

Is there a way I can search for such a string?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using some sort of escape sequence for one or more letters? have you tried concatenating strings to form the search without it containing the literal reserved word?

Comment: I have tried surrounding it in square brackets and using "" instead of ''. What do you mean by concatenating string?

Comment: Is this something which happens only when you use an ODBC connection? Can you run the query directly against the database?

Comment: Yes, happens on the ODBC connection as well as when I run it in Access.

Comment: Could you try `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE AccountNumber = "Su" & "m"`? (assuming this is your literal query?

Comment: Here's the actual SQL, if that helps you more `SELECT     ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.SALES_LEDGER.*, ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.SYS_FOREIGN_CURRENCY.CURRENCY_DESCRIPTION
FROM         ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.SALES_LEDGER, ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.SYS_FOREIGN_CURRENCY
WHERE     ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.SALES_LEDGER.FOREIGN_CURRENCY = ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.SYS_FOREIGN_CURRENCY.THIS_RECORD AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 'Sum'`

Comment: The query is called from a C# method and takes the account number as a parameter which it then uses to construct this string, which it then passes to the OdbcDataAdapter

Comment: Sorry, I know that the problem is due to the quoted reserved word as the query works fine with other words. It just fails when searching for account numbers like "Max" and "Sum"

Answer (score 1):

Parameterise the string you wish to use as part of the WHERE clause and as I had the same problem when using the keyword 'PRIORITY'. After modifying the C# code to use parameters, it worked.

```
using (OdbcCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   command.CommandText = "SELECT account_ref FROM SALES_LEDGER WHERE account_ref = '?'";
   command.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("?", accountCode));

   using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for 'Sum' specifically. You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE AccountNumber LIKE('%Sum%')
```