# Should I avoid naming a SQL table by a ODBC Reserved Keyword when I'm using JDBC?

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, keyword, reserved

As indicated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

> The following words are reserved for use in ODBC function calls. These words do not constrain the minimum SQL grammar; however, to ensure compatibility with drivers that support the core SQL grammar, applications should avoid using these keywords.

This list includes the word I'd like to use as a table name, `Session`, and seems to state pretty clearly that I should avoid its use.

But I don't have any current intention to use ODBC - I'll be using JDBC - and I don't really understand how bad this would be if, down the road, I changed my mind. Can anyone explain in more detail whether naming my table this way truly is a bad idea?

I'm looking more for personal experience than further technical references that don't convey the experience of dealing with the problems that might arise. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830139/odbc-sql-using-a-reserved-word-in-a-where-clause) looks pretty unpleasant, but how often does it come up that one might switch from JDBC to ODBC realistically?

Comment: Why not just name the table something else instead of spending all this time worrying about it. Name is UserSession or SessionInfo, SessionData whatever and be done with it.

Comment: The word Session is company-speak for what data this table holds. It's in a zillion documents. It's simply added confusion to have this table named anything else, even something close.

Comment: Then if changing it is too much effort keep it the way it is.

Comment: Well, I can't change it in company speak and existing documents. So it'd mean that every DB/engineer working with, say, SessionData, would need to know to talk to others in the company only about Session, as SessionData is something else. But what kinds of issues will arise if, down the road, we're trying to use ODBC? Strange bugs, difficult to find errors, extra care required in creating queries, etc.? What's it like to end up with the situation where using such a keyword doesn't appear to matter at first, but later matters. Will it matter A LOT or just a little?

Comment: Keywords are a pain to work with but not that big of a deal. You just have to wrap the column name in square brackets. So instead of "select * from Session" it would be "select * from [Session]".

Comment: Just a note for @SeanLange, [ and ] are T-SQL quote characters, standard ANSI SQL uses " to quote things so the more portable way would be SELECT * FROM "Session".

Comment: @KylePorter I always chuckle at the concept of portability when it comes to sql code. Realistically changing the DBMS frequently just doesn't happen. And when you have to write code to make it portable you have to eliminate a number of the advantages from whatever dialect you are working with. I know a lot of people though who maintain they want to write their code as portable as possible.